# What is the number of outcomes of this die counting problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, dice

I have this counting problem I would like someone to help me resolve. The question is:

> When playing [Yahtzee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee), you roll *five* regular 6-sided dice. How many different outcomes are possible from a single roll? *The order* of the dice *does not matter*.

The way I calculated it, I reckoned that the first dice would give either of 6 outcomes, so for the second to the fifth die. So, I said the outcomes would be `6^5`. But the textbook gave the answer as a combination of C(10,5).
Can someone explain to me how he went about getting C(10,5)? it baffles me.

Comment: This is a [Stars and Bars problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), where we are counting the number of $6-$tuples of non-negative integers that sum to $5$.  It follows that the number is $\binom {6+5-1}{5}=\binom {10}5$.

Comment: "*...from a single roll?* **The order of the dice does not matter**"  The answer of $6^5$ is the correct answer to the wrong question... the question where the order of the dice *does* matter.

Comment: Now, I get it if this is a stars and bars problem. How I see it is that it means each side can be mapped to more than one die, therefore it would not be evaluated the way I expected.

Comment: To get a $6-$ tuple out of a roll, just count the number of $1's$, $2's$, etc. that you get.  Thus, for example the roll $\{6,5,6,2,6\}$ gives us the $6-$tuple $(0,1,0,0,1,3)$ because there is one $2$, one $5$, and three $6's$ and zero of $\{1,3,4\}$

Comment: Similarly having rolled $(5,2,6,6,6)$ (*which if we treated order as being relevant would count as a different roll than $(6,5,6,2,6)$*) will *also* correspond to $(0,1,0,0,1,3)$ since in both we rolled one $2$, one $5$ and three $6$'s *in some order*.  Since the total number of each result was the same, these are treated as effectively being "*the same outcome*" here.

Comment: Before leaving you to digest all of this... I must emphasize that using this for counting is perfectly fine.  If you attempt to use this manner of thinking in a probability question however you will likely run into trouble.  It is a common mistake to think that the outcomes counted by stars-and-bars are equally likely to occur, leading to erroneous calculations like the probability all five of the dice if rolled show a $1$ is $\frac{1}{\binom{10}{5}}$ if you don't care about order of dice.  It is not.  Dividing number of good outcomes over all outcomes only works when they are equally likely.

Comment: To explain the stars-and-bars representation, a roll like $\{6,5,6,2,6\}$ can be represented as
`|□|||□|□□□`
where each "star" `□` (there are five) represents one die, and each bar `|` represents a "boundary", so the first bar separates the ones from the twos, the second bar separates the twos from the threes, etc., until the fifth and last bar which is the separation between fives and sixes. When you think about it, every roll can be represented in this way in a unique manner, using five "stars" and five bars, and conversely every permutation of these ten symbols is a valid roll.

Answer (score 1):

Following ${\tt @lulu}$ above comment ( "$\ldots$we are counting the number of $6$−tuples of non-negative integers that sum to $5$". ):
\begin{align}
\sum_{d_{1} = 0}^{6}\ldots\sum_{d_{6} = 0}^{6}
\left[z^{5}\right]z^{d_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ d_{6}} & =
\left[z^{5}\right]\sum_{d_{1} = 0}^{\infty}\ldots
\sum_{d_{6} = 0}^{\infty}z^{d_{1}\ +\ \cdots\ +\ d_{6}}
=
\left[z^{5}\right]\left(\sum_{d = 0}^{\infty}z^{d}\right)^{6}
\\[5mm] & =
\left[z^{5}\right]\left(1 - z\right)^{-6} = {-6 \choose 5}\left(-1\right)^{5} =
{6 + 5 - 1 \choose 5}
\\[5mm] & = {10 \choose 5}
=\bbox[10px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{\large252}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

To see how to apply stars and bars, let $x_i$ be the number of $i's $ you get when you roll the $5$ dice. So we want the number of 6-tuples that satisfy $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6 = 5$ and each $x_i$ can range from $0$ to $5$. This is standard stars and bars.

Answer (score 0):

> The order of the dice does not matter.

What order the 5 dice show the numbers in is of no importance. The only thing that distinguishes one outcome from another is  a *different number* of $1's,2's,3's,4's,5's$ or $6's$. As an example, $(1,2,2,2,4)$ and $(2,2,4,2,1)$ are identical outcomes, as far as the game is concerned.

Let's say the number of dice that showed $i$ in a roll were $x_i$, $1≤i≤6$.

The number of outcomes would be the number of ordered 6-touples $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)$ that satisfy the following conditions:

1. Each $x_i$is a non-negative integer
2. $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=5$, since the number of dice rolled was 5.

Number of solutions of such a system is 10C5, easy enough to calculate.
Check https://youtu.be/DQHg_UcS3hQ for help with this calculation.